# Search all of my past questions that had images or screenshots in them?

Tags: support, search, images

Is there a way to search all my questions that contain images or screenshots inlined with `![]()`?

I tried `body:imgur` but it only searches for *text*.

I tried `url:imgur.com` but it only searches for *links*, and not inlined images with `![]()` syntax.

Comment: Have you tried searching for the file extension types?

Comment: Actually, and this is stupuid, but `url:imgur.com` actually works! don't know why I thought it didn't earlier but it does work, and shows results that have images. And so does `url:*.png`

Comment: @laggingreflex that's worth a self answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was mistaken.

`url:imgur.com` actually works. It correctly shows results that have images.

And so does `url:*.png`

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no built-in way.

It would be nice if the search engine supported a parameter like `hasimage:yes`.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156639/add-hasimage1-or-img1-advanced-search-operators