# Indicating enclosed photos on question list pages?

Tags: feature-request, images, homepage

Some kinds of questions, on some sites, are vastly improved by the inclusion of images. For example, on https://bicycles.stackexchange.com, the question ["schwinn identification problems"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42020/schwinn-identification-problems) is essentially unanswerable without an attached photo.

This suggestion is to indicate, on the question summary, that the question body includes one or more photos. For the above example question, I'm thinking of something like:

[image]

This would have at least two benefits:

- Indicate to readers that a question with an image is likely a quality question
- Indicate to question authors that attaching an image attracts slightly more attention

I doubt that these subtle benefits are so much that people would start attaching unrelated images to their questions. Useless images would quickly be edited away.

Comment: You might be surprised what lengths some people will go to for subtle benefits.  But there's a flip side: people with slow, expensive or limited data connections might make a point of *avoiding* questions with pictures.

Comment: Related request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156639/add-hasimage1-or-img1-advanced-search-operators.

Answer (score 11):

In my opinion, the mere appearance of a photo doesn't justify calling the post out to that degree in the main question listings.

That's some pretty valuable real estate. If I were to see an icon highlighting a post among those relatively plain listings, I'd assume it must be pretty special. And if I clicked through, I'd also be pretty disappointed.

I don't hate the idea; I like the icon. I just think the *weight* of this feature is **disproportionate to the value proposition it implies.**